# How to update values of a ComBobox in java? I'm using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, combobox

So this is a little program for my java lessons in school and I need to be able to update the items on a ComboBox so the one that has been previously selected does not appear any more. For example, the combobox has the numbers from 1-10, if a user picks the number 1, a new user will be able to select a new number without the awkardness of selecting the one that has been taken.

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).  You could remove the selected item from the `ComboBoxModel`, but, then how do you know what they selected?  A better idea might be to have two `JComboBox`s, when an item is selected in the first, that item is removed from the second.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the ComboBoxModel from the JComboBox by calling `getModel()` on it. It should implement the MutableComboBoxModel interface, and so you can cast the object returned to this, and call the MutableComboBoxModel's `removeElement(...)` method, passing in the element that you wish to remove.

Comment: Wowho, another one over the 200k wall ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks, but while I'm almost there, I'm not quite there. As I told Andrew, I'm riding this near dead horse, Swing, into the StackOverflow sunset, yeehaw!

Comment: Yeah, I remember that moment to ;)